# Is my proof of $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}\right)=\infty $ accurate?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> prove $$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}\right)=\infty $$

My proof:
For any $M ∈ ℝ$ there exists $N ∈ ℕ$ such that n>N (n is sufficiently large) and so choose $a_n$>M

$\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}\right)$ > M

$\frac{\frac{n^2}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{n}{n}+\frac{1}{n}}$ >M

n>M

This shows for any M I can find $a_n$ where n>M, therefore the sequence approaches infinity.

Does this make sense??

Comment: Work on $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-1)$ instead.

Comment: A mathematical proof consists of logical sentences, not fragments of symbols. "Does this make sense?" No. I suggest you check your books/notes the **definition** of $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ and try to see how the definition fits in this exercise.

Comment: i did try using the definition, wasn't trying to do a formal proof or anything just wondering if the math was correct :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove by the definition that

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}\right)=\infty $$

you must show that if $M>0$ then there is an $n_0>0$ such that for any $n>n_0$, $\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}>M$.

Proof: Let $M>0$. Let $n_0=M+1$. Then if $n>n_0$

\begin{eqnarray}
n-1&>&M\\
(n-1)\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+1}&>&M\\
\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}&>&M
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Ok this makes sense! is my proof sort of equivalent to this or not at all?

Comment: @user520403 Notice that the formulas in this proof come in the opposite order from yours. Also, you ended up with $n > M,$ but in fact we need $n > M+1$ as used in this proof.

Comment: @user520403 It is ok to investigate how to prove something by "working backward." But that is merely an investigation, it is not a proof. You have to be able to turn the steps around in order to turn it into a proof. And that is what you present, not the investigative steps.

Answer (score 3):

Simplify the limit first:
$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{n^2-1}{n+1} = \lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n+1} = \lim_{n\to ∞} (n-1)$$

Hence proving $$\lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{n^2-1}{n+1} = ∞$$ is proving $$\lim_{n\to ∞} (n-1) = ∞$$

Answer (score 0):

Factor with difference of squares to get 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-1)=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that because:

$$(n-1)(n+1)=n^2-1$$we have that:

$$n\neq -1 \implies \frac{n^2-1}{n+1}=n-1$$

Since we are taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, the condition can be ignored so we just find:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-1)$$
which is trivially $\infty$